# PHP Script: mkdir permission denied - best way to handle customer support?

Tags: php, apache, permissions, chmod, mkdir

I sell a PHP script that needs to make some directories. Now I know that I can just tell the user to chmod the directory to 777, but that doesn't seem very secure. Is there another (safe) way? These are novice users that have bought a PHP script, so I cannot expect them to configure apache differently, most are on shared hosts anyway.

The script is creating thumbnails of an image directory the user supplies. Since it's apache that creates the files, it probably needs 777? Is there any way around chmod that is easy for users to do?

Thanks,
Wesley

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019194/chmod-777-in-php

Comment: Create a FAQ on your website and maintain it. You can not automatically deal with it. Additionally offer installation support for your product.

Answer (score 0):

[Which path is the php script supposed to create directories into?]

You just need the path to belong to the user who runs the php script, then the permission could simply be 700 instead of 777.

Comment: The script is creating thumbnails of an image directory the user supplies. Since it's apache that creates the files, wouldn't it need 777 (ftp username different from apache username)

Comment: well, given these premises, I don't see any other way than change permissions. Alternatively you may consider to modify your script and let him create the thumbnails path inside a apache username writable directory. Probably you already considered it, I don't know in depth your needs.